# Can I change the return type of a function based on the property of a parameter?

Tags: typescript

I've got a utility function that wraps `document.querySelector`

```
function querySelector<T extends HTMLElement>(selector: string) {
    return document.querySelector<T>(selector);
}
```

I extended it to give me the option to throw an error if it can't find the element.

```
function querySelector<T extends HTMLElement>(
    selector: string,
    options: {
        required?: boolean
    } = {}
) {

    const element = document.querySelector<T>(selector);

    if (options.required && !element) {
        throw new ReferenceError(`Can't find an element that matches "${selector}"`);
    }

    return element;

}
```

The problem I'm having is that `document.querySelector` will return the element or `null`, so TypeScript assumes that the return value of my `querySelector` function will be `T | null` (in all fairness, without telling the function that the element is required, that's exactly what it would return).

```
const foo = querySelector(".foo", { required: true });
foo.addEventListener("abc", () => {});
// ts(18047) 'foo' is possibly 'null'
```

Looking at [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/svfvol/conditional_return_type_based_on_parameter_type/), it seems that it's possible to change the return type of my function based on the parameters, but I can't work out how to get that checking the property of an object parameter.

My first thought was to pass another parameter to the angular brackets, but that didn't seem to work at all.

```
type QuerySelectorOptions = Partial<{
    required: boolean
}>;

function querySelector<T extends HTMLElement, O extends QuerySelectorOptions>(
    selector: string,
    options: O = {}
    // ts(2322) "... could be instantiated with a different subtype ..."
) {
    // ...
}
```

I can't seem to reference `options` without something like `O`.

```
function querySelector<T extends HTMLElement>(
    selector: string,
    options: QuerySelectorOptions = {}
): options.required /* ... */ { // ts(2503) Cannot find namespace 'options'
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way that I can change the return type of my function based on the property of one of the parameters or am I just asking for the impossible/impractical?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix: just use the non-null assertion operator, then `element` is never null, but it can be undefined.

```
function querySelector<T extends HTMLElement>(
    selector: string,
    options: {
        required?: boolean
    } = {}
) {

    const element = document.querySelector<T>(selector)!; // Makes element T instead of T | null

    if (options.required && !element) {
        throw new ReferenceError(`Can't find an element that matches "${selector}"`);
    }

    return element;
}
```

Comment: `element` might be `null` and if `options.required` isn't set to `true` then that's what I'd want to get back. Using the non-null assertion seems to never return `null`

Comment: then `return element ? element : null;`